# Looking for an interactive, user-directed presentation creator

Tags: presentation

What I'm trying to do is create a presentation for a client that consists of various idea/concept slides. These ideas interconnect and branch, and don't necessarily need to be viewed in a defined order for all "slides". The thought was that certain slides might offer various "branching points" where the area of the slide that you clicked on determined the slides you saw next.

So, for example, you start on Slide 1. Slide 1 has a few places you can click which take you to Slides 2, 5 and 13 respectively. Slides 3 and 4 branch off of Slide 2. Slides  6, 7 and 8 branch off of Slide 5, and Slides 9-12 are attached to Slide 8.

Does anyone know any software (preferably web-based) that would allow you to do something like this?

Comment: Could these "areas" or "places" simply be hyperlinks (i.e., linked words)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Prezi](http://www.prezi.com):

- free
- online
- presentation tool
- import from PowerPoint
- can branch off to other slides
- nice looking pre made templates
- easy to use
- windows/ios/osx app

[Here's an example](https://prezi.com/kfpnjzct2dsr/concept-split-and-join/) of branching off to other slides (by [this person](https://getsatisfaction.com/prezi/topics/recommend_multiple_paths_through_a_prezi#reply_4327194), not me!).

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of thing that [Twine](http://twinery.org//) would be very useful for, while it is not "presentation" software it is intended for interactive stories where the user selects their own path through the story.

- Easy to use
- Can include graphics
- Free
- Cross Platform (Mac/Linux/Windows) or [online](http://twinery.org/2/#welcome) authoring system
- Your finished product can be viewed through most web browsers providing that java is enabled.

Comment: Awesome, I'll go check it out and make sure it fits my needs, but at first glance it seems very promising!